# Sum of Quantity for the Max price in same time

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, max, aggregate-functions

Table data :

```
Time    BUY  SELL   BUY_Qty SELL_Qty
3:00    20     10      5     2
3:00    20     10      5     1
3:00    20     10      5     4
3:00    10     20      2     3
3:00    10     20      2     3
```

Expected result from the above data :

```
Time    max(BUY)  MIN(SELL)   BUY_Qty SELL_Qty
3:00       20          10       15      7
```

Comment: Do you want to group it by time?

Comment: yes. I want to group it based on time

Comment: I want the sum of BUY Quantity for the max buy price and sum of SELL Quantity for the min sell price

Comment: Is this SQL or.  ..?

Comment: in ORACLE, I need a oracle query

Comment: @user2814847 - Did you check my answer?

Comment: As far as I know your issue should be targeted by Md. Suman Kabir's answer, so I deleted my not complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you can use in oracle :

```
select t1.Time, max_buy, min_sell, SUM(t1.BUY_Qty), SUM(t1.SELL_Qty) 
from table1 t1
join(SELECT Time, MAX(BUY) as max_buy, MIN(SELL) as min_sell
    FROM Table1 GROUP BY Time) t2 
    on t1.time=t2.time and t1.buy=t2.max_buy
group by t1.Time, max_buy, min_sell
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be94a/1)